# List values is not displaying for more rows

Tags: java, list

List is not displaying more no of records > ihave read data from 2 excel files and when i run the follwing program it is showing only 1 row when there are 50 rows.

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(fil); // reading from file 
String array1[]=new String[50];
s.next(); s.next(); s.next(); s.next();
int i=0;
String[] values= new String[55];
while(s.hasNext())
{  
  String field=s.next();
  values=field.split(","); 
}
List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();

for(String x:values)
{
  list1.add(x);
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a proper reason for that:
You iterate the rows with the scanner all right, but then you **replace** the values array in each iteration. Thus you will get only the last row in values eventually.

You might do it like that:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList();
while(s.hasNext())
{  
  String field=s.next();
  for (String value : field.split(",")) {
     values.add(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: better use String field=(String)s.next(); and I would use Iterator instead of for(Object o:Collection). Your friend Yoncho

Comment: Off-topic to my friend: Well both your comments are not totally relevant and correct: s.next() already returns a String, no need to cast. Furthermore I am very interested in seeing what kind of iterator are you proposing over String[]? Are you going to include a whole third-party lib only for that?

Comment: OK, you are right, I guess I am not getting used to see such a chaining  for (String value : field.split(",")) and I need more coffee. I would take field.split(",") in a variable and use the old-fashioned for cycle. This was supposed to be poke you comment, too bad it lit my personality as an idiot :D

Answer (score 2):

Your `while (s.hasNext())` loop overwrites the `values` array for each row, so only the values from the last row are added to the list. Try moving the `for` loop inside the `while` loop so that each row is added.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving into values the list of cells of the last row.

Each time you process a row (the `while` block). You place into values all the cells of the last row, forgetting the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

In the following:

```
while(s.hasNext())
{  
    String field=s.next();
    values=field.split(","); // <--- overwrites previous line's fields
}
```

the previous contents of `values` is discarded whenever you assign to it. Therefore, your code only keeps the most recent line.

To fix, you need to use a 2D array (one dimension for rows and one for columns) or a 2D collection (an ArrayList of ArrayLists, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these lines:

```
String[] values= new String[55];
while(s.hasNext())
{  
  String field=s.next();
  values=field.split(","); 
}
```

In every iteration `values` is overwritten. You should declare the `list1` before the loop and add the `values` as soon as they are initialized.